# Why auto-completion does not work in this case?

Tags: completion, fuzzy-matching

In general, I am pretty happy with the tab-completion provided by Emacs. However, I would like to avoid situations like this one.

While programming in Lisp with Slime and SBCL, I am doing a let-binding of this expression `(render-url url-instance))` in the following code snippet:

```lisp
 (dolist (url-instance  (urls-visited-over-threshold (url->bookmark-visit-threshold *browser*)))
      (if (is-url-new-to-bookmarks-p (render-url url-instance))
          (if-confirm ("Do you want to bookmark ~a?" (render-url url-instance))
                      (bookmark-url :url (render-url url-instance)))))))
```

After creating the let-binding with the `url-address` I thought I would be able to replace it using tab-completion

```lisp
(let ((url-address (render-url url-instance)))
        (if (is-url-new-to-bookmarks-p url-address)
            (if-confirm ("Bookmark ~a?" url-address)
                        (bookmark-url :url (render-url url-instance)))))
```

However, as I remove `(render-url url-instance)` and I start to type `url-a...` to achieve `url-address` I *cannot* do tab completion. And I have saved the file.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: This seems more like a content for bug report rather than a Q&A site.

Comment: FWIW, this example works fine in `emacs-lisp-mode`. Try the SLIME bug tracker.

Comment: @Dmitry I did not know this could be a bug.

Comment: The important thing is to evaluate the the let expression, not to save the file.