# Why is auto-complete using capitalized words? Is there a way to change the default of suggestions while in Slime's Buffer?

Tags: auto-complete-mode, slime, capitalization

Recently, I have started using this emacs package: [auto-complete](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete). It works and I am enjoying it. I mainly use emacs to work in Common Lisp (SBCL) with Slime.

Unfortunately, the first suggestion that appears is always capitalized case in the Slime's REPL buffer which annoys me:

[image]

Is there a way to change the default to have the first suggestion lower-cased?

In the print above, my desired first suggestion is, actually, the last one.

Thanks.

Comment: I think most people use `company-mode` instead of `autocomplete` these days. There's nothing wrong with the latter, but I have the feeling it's not so well maintained. Also, don't underestimate the built-in completion mechanism of emacs (i.e. the minibuffer). Also, please eval the following in Emacs: `(info "(slime) Compound Completion")`.

Comment: Thanks, André! Something weird happens with the built-in completion mechanism in my env. I need to fix it: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/66550/why-auto-completion-does-not-work-in-this-case . Not sure if it is a bug. But, while I do not solve the built-in stuff, package auto-complete has been helping me. I will follow your advice and try this company package :)

Comment: Hmm... I had an idea. What happens if you add this to your init: `(setq slime-completion-at-point-functions '(slime-c-p-c-completion-at-point slime-filename-completion slime-simple-completion-at-point))`?

Comment: Another suggestion I have is to give the commands `dabbrev-expand` and `hippie-expand` a try. The former is usually bound to `M-/`.